# Convert Curl "-I --user" to Python Requests

Tags: python, rest, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert a cURL command to python and I'm struggling

```
curl -I --user username:password https://an.api.on.the.internet/
```

My current attempt is:

```
import requests
cur = requests.get('https://an.api.on.the.internet', auth='username:password')
```

Could anyone help me convert it? thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use

```
requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
```

See the section on [Basic Authentication](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/) in the `requests` documentation.

Comment: thanks, I get a response from the api. Interestingly it is a different response from the curl to python. Both succeed, but have differing results. Any idea why this is? what does the"-i" do?

Comment: But the authentication succeeds (you don't get a `401 Unauthorized`)? Then that's a different question, could be anything. As for `-I` (not the same as `-i`), please consult `man curl`. It does a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`, fetching only the headers of a resource. See http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request on `requests.head()`